# Call swift from c

Tags: c++, c, swift, interop

I saw someone use swift code from android, using @_cdecl swift functions. I am able to compile to native using swiftc -emit-object, but when trying to link, I cant get the linker to work correctly..

I am trying to use g++ or clang(++) to compile and link a native swift object, has someone successfully done this already?

The errors I get are listed below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 

"__T0S2SBp21_builtinStringLiteral_Bw17utf8CodeUnitCountBi1_7isASCIItcfC", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"__T0SSN", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"__T0s27_allocateUninitializedArraySayxG_BptBwlFyp_Tgq5", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"__T0s5printySayypGd_SS9separatorSS10terminatortF", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"__T0s5printySayypGd_SS9separatorSS10terminatortFfA0_", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"__T0s5printySayypGd_SS9separatorSS10terminatortFfA1_", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"_swift_bridgeObjectRelease", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
"_swift_bridgeObjectRetain", referenced from:
      __T04main4testyyF in main.o
```

So basically I have two questions, can it be done and how?
John.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled against the right architecture?

Comment: Could you add some example code showing how you define the Swift functions and how you declare and call the functions in C++?

Comment: It compiles now, thanx to the hint for the right architecture, except it complains about duplicate symbols (_main). Of course there is one in my c code, but my guess is that the swift library get a _main injected?    
    Duplicate symbol _main in:
    /var/folders/mj/163htgjs78z18dr4lkh5n3tm0000gn/T/m-d42d2f.o
    main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Comment: I have it working... Super! thanx for the help!

Comment: Maybe write an answer and mark it as valid so someone looking at this question in the future finds a solution? :)

Comment: good point, gimme a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanx to amine.ahd's pointer, I had the iphoneos toolchain location linked instead of the mac osx's.

The following command actually compiled and let me run a c program that calls a swift native library, even with parameters (char* on the c side, UnsafePointer on the swift side).

```
clang -o m m.o -lshared -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx  -L.
```

*-lshared is the libshared.so library that is compiled using the following command:

```
clang -shared -o libshared.so main.o -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx
```

Notice the main.o, this got produced using the following command:

```
swiftc main.swift -emit-object
```

Thanx for the hints

Comment: [Swift Meets C/C++](https://gist.github.com/HiImJulien/c79f07a8a619431b88ea33cca51de787) provides examples including Swift source, C/C++ source code and shell commands. One example includes how to specify and pass a function parameter.